# react-native-i18n module linking with expo

Tags: react-native, internationalization, expo

I am building an app using Create-React-Native-App.  As such, my testing and development is in Expo.  I am looking for a solution to help with i18n, mostly translations and RTL.  I found that ex-react-native-i18n works great, until I try ejecting to create the App, because it needs expo.  (Which I don't need or want in the production App)

with `react-native-i18n` I get this error:
`react-native-i18n module is not correctly linked`

I tried `react-native link` and `yarn link` without success.  The ReadMe page for `react-native-i18n` has extensive instructions for manual linking, but only for AFTER ejecting.

What am I missing here?
Is there a better solution that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible to get that module working before ejecting.

Have you tried this library?
https://github.com/xcarpentier/ex-react-native-i18n

Mark

Comment: as I mentioned in my original post I did.  And that was fine until I tried to eject.

Which makes me think...  How similar are the two librarys?  Could I define ex-react-native-i18n as a development dependency and react-native-i18n a production dependency and switch between the two on ejecting?  Would that work?  How would one go about doing that?